# In a struct, is it valid to implement operator== via Equals, but not override Equals and GetHashCode?

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading, equals, equals-operator

Is this valid?

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }

    public static bool operator ==(MyStruct a, MyStruct b)
    {
        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyStruct a, MyStruct b)
    {
        return !a.Equals(b);
    }
}
```

(I know it's slightly inefficient because Object.Equals uses reflection for value types by default. But is it valid?)

I'm asking because ReSharper highlights it and warns me that `MyStruct defines operator '==' or operator '!=' but does not provide 'Object.Equals(object o)' and 'Object.GetHashCode()'`.

Comment: The warning is because of what Damien is saying: it defies developers' expectations.

Comment: IMHO in Foo { get; set; } the setter is a bit weird. Value types should be immutable, A setter just fools you in a very complex web of (useless) updating. If a single value changes in a struct, just create a complete new struct. e.g.: A point is a struct. And you cannot change the X or Y of a Point. Because points are "static" entities, you cannot "move" them. If a Point changes, it has to be another Point, i.e. a new Struct. Conclusion: Make all Properties readonly and pass values only by constructor.

Comment: Caspar: People keep saying that but I strongly disagree. If I were to make the setter private, users of struct Point would just change their `p.X++;` to the less-readable `p = new Point(p.X + 1, p.Y);`, or something weird like `p = p.WithX(p.X + 1);`, with no benefit at all.

Comment: The benefit of immutable value types is not simply syntax related. It's that they are much easier to reason about than mutable value types. Eric Lippert can probably explain this better than anyone - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs.aspx. However, if you're aware of the evils, and everyone that interacts with your mutable value types in the future is OK with that, go for it.

Comment: @Alex Humphrey: Mutable value types are fine, provided that they never mutate "this", which is to say that the only ways of mutating them are either via public mutable fields or via public methods which modify a struct passed by reference.  There are some limitations in .net's handling of them (especially properties), but such limitations may be overcome by defining a Holder<T> class which contains a single public field of type T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valid? Yes. But it doesn't buy you anything.

Comment: It buys me the ability to compare two MyStruct instances via '==', doesn't it?

Comment: @Stefan: What, you hate typing `Equals`? ;) I meant that it doesn't buy you anything that you didn't already have (with `Equals`). Typically with a `struct` it's a good idea to actually write out the equality logic to reap the performance benefit; but it sounds like you already knew about that, based on your comment about reflection. So, if you really prefer `==` to `Equals` but understand that it's not actually giving you anything aside from that... go for it.

Comment: Yes, I do prefer == to Equals because I like to treat my value types the same way as I treat primitive types. Thanks.

Comment: @Stefan: Totally reasonable. I'd still recommend overriding `Equals` to avoid the reflection overhead. But that's just me.

Answer (score 4):

I think [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xiangfan/archive/2008/09/01/magic-behind-valuetype-equals.aspx) may be interesting.

Comment: Thanks. The float-issue is minor, but worth knowing about.

Answer (score 2):

It's valid, in terms of the fact that it compiles. But it's "invalid" in the sense that it breaks all expectations of users of your class - the framework design guidelines specify that you shouldn't implement functionality that only exists in operator overloads - that such methods should be accessible in other ways. And the standard is that Object.Equals and operator== implement the same functionality.

[(Can only find the 1.1 version of the guidelines at the moment)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2sk3x8a7(v=VS.71).aspx):

> Provide alternate signatures. Most
>   languages do not support operator
>   overloading. For this reason, it is a
>   CLS requirement for all types that
>   overload operators to include a
>   secondary method with an appropriate
>   domain-specific name that provides the
>   equivalent functionality. It is a
>   Common Language Specification (CLS)
>   requirement to provide this secondary
>   method. The following example is
>   CLS-compliant.

Comment: I believe I'm not breaking the guidelines. For my struct, Object.Equals and operator== implement the same functionality, because the latter just calls the former.

Comment: @Stefan: That is true. But ReSharper is not aware that you've "linked up" the methods in this way. I think it's just that generally, when you see that the `==` and `!=` operators have been implemented for a type, you'd expect to see `Equals` (and thus `GetHashCode`) overridden.